# Why is element.scrollLeft so slow in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have been timing how long it takes to say

```
div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
div.scrollLeft;
```

where mydiv has a set width and overflow-x: scroll.

In chrome and FF, this object access (its not a fn call right, why does it have to do any work?) is essentially free (never more than a couple ms). In IE though (6,7,8) it is on the order of a couple seconds if the div is wide enough. What can I do about this?

Comment: How wide is wide?  And it's property access, which could be as consuming as a function access if it is implemented as a getter/setter.

Comment: 9,000 px wide or possible more

Comment: if you want answers instead of "why" you should ask "how to do…"

Comment: can u post the code or any url where we can check it out?